# Spark submit, spark shell or pyspark not taking default environment values

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-compute-engine, hadoop-yarn

I have installed Hadoop and Spark on Google Cloud using Click To Deploy. I am trying to run the spark shell and spark submit to test the installation. But when I try

```
spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

I get error Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory > max configured, requestedMemory=6383, maxMemory=5999

The problem is when I don't provide --executor-memory 1G or some value , it doesn't pick the default 1G value and don't know why but yarn allocates the max memory to the executor.
Commands with arguments and without arguments

```
pyspark --master yarn-client --executor-memory 1G --num-executors 1 --verbose
    Parsed arguments:
      master                  yarn-client
      deployMode              null
      executorMemory          1G
      numExecutors            1

pyspark --master yarn --verbose
Parsed arguments:
  master                  yarn
  deployMode              null
  executorMemory          null
  numExecutors            null
```

Is this a spark bug or google cloud configuration issue? Is there anyway we can set the default values.